# django - "urls" function sometime included in urls.py

Tags: django

Why is it in some `urls.py` files you see `url(..)` and in others you see `(..)`.

For example

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('hello','article.view.hello')
)
```

and in others i see :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('article/', include('article.urls'))
)
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear in your question, please?

Comment: Yeah, I wanna know too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `patterns()` makes the use of `url()` optional. Going forward, however, `patterns` will be deprecated and you will have to always use `url`. See [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22218):

> The other thing that `patterns` provides besides the prefix parameter is automatically wrapping plain tuples in `urlpatterns` in `url()`. I think removing this and forcing usage of `url()` will be a good cleanup.

So you should get in the habit of always using `url`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for clarification with your edit:

- First one points to the view
- second one allows you to add another patterns list from separate module (or from the same one)

But usage of `url` is purely for convenience (but will be required in django 2.0). You can see the check here:

[https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/urls/**init**.py#L55](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/urls/__init__.py#L55)

Comment: I doubt it's for _convenience_ because when I remove it from my urls, I get a syntax error.

Comment: Actually, you're right. That's just for convenience. I get a syntax error in only one project, not all.