# Django URLConf - url() function - can it be omitted?

Tags: django, django-urls, urlconf

I just found out that the following code gives the same result:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

as this one:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

So, what is the utility of using the url() function in the first way of coding?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260434/django-urls-function-sometime-included-in-urls-py/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently these two options are essentially the same, since in the second case `Django` applies `url()` function for each of your tuples under the hood. Quote from the [`django.conf.url.patterns`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/urls/__init__.py#L54) source code:

```
def patterns(prefix, *args):
    ...
    pattern_list = []
    for t in args:
        if isinstance(t, (list, tuple)):  # < HERE
            t = url(prefix=prefix, *t)
        elif isinstance(t, RegexURLPattern):
            t.add_prefix(prefix)
        pattern_list.append(t)
    return pattern_list
```

Also, as @Kevin Christopher Henry already noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23260596/771848), `urlpatterns` is becoming deprecated (see [Deprecate 'prefix' arg to django.conf.urls.patterns](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22218) ticket and this [pull request](https://github.com/django/django/pull/2504)). Without having `urlpatterns`, we'll have to explicitly call `url()` on each of the items of the url list. Better get into the habit of using it.